# Implementing URL JSON API Data into Website

Tags: api, json

I've recently been messing around with my own Game server, and I want to implement a status page on my website, so if the game Server ever goes down players have a place to go to find out what went wrong by viewing live data from a JSON API. This site: `https://unturned-servers.net/` has a JSON API with all of the information that I need players to see, what's the simplest way to implement this into my website? As I'm only using the Elementor page builder, I don't have a lot of scripting experience and wanted to know what the simplest way would be and if someone could break it down for me.

Comment: Please remove your API key from the question!

Comment: Whoops sorry, it doesn't hold much valuable information but thanks for the edit.